# Why is encoding changed?

Tags: php, ajax, sqlite, encoding

I have a project on local webserver, and all files are in UTF-8, also sqlite database in UTF-8, and it's ok with german letters a,o,u with dots (umlauts), but on the hosting they become , it's definite if I had different types of files with different encodings, but it doesn't work on hosting only, why?

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
require("dbconnect.php");
...

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY CREATED " . $order . " LIMIT(10)";
    $query = $dbo->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->fetchAll();
    renderTable($result);

...

function renderTable($queryResult) {
...
echo "<td>",ucwords(strtolower($row['CUSTNAME'])),"</td>";
...
```

[On hosting and on test server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2tzU.jpg)

Comment: Well, i would first check if hosting database uses the same encoding, check in specific database table if it's stored as `o` or `?`. Also do you initialize a db connection as UTF-8?

Comment: First of all check if the overall hosting is using that encoding. Perhaps try to contact your hoster about that problem as you have it running all UTF-8 and checked it on your own host.

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos stores as o, hoster isn't mine, so can't check, is there some solution to set all with htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all, it was an strtolower built-in function, I use it to change caps names to general, and for unicode it's recommended to use mb_strtolower

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this in dbconnect.php

```
$dpo->exec("set names utf8");
```

Comment: Yes, it's in dbconnect.php `code`try {
    $dbo = new PDO("sqlite:../data/clients.db");
    $dbo->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $dbo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}`code`

Comment: Have you tried all this?
[link]https://www.toptal.com/php/a-utf-8-primer-for-php-and-mysql

I meet this problem before with Vietnamese and did many things to fix it

Comment: what do you mean "all"?